# Is $S^1$ Hausdorff with respect to induced topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I am not sure if this is correct:

Is $S^1 = \{ (x,y):x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ Hausdorff with respect to induced topology ($f:X\to Y$, the induced topology on $X$ by $f$ is $\{ f^{-1}(U): U \in \mathcal{T}^Y\})$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$

Any hints how to prove?
Thank you :)

Comment: What is $f$?  is it the inclusion map?

Comment: Not necessarily, it can be any map. That's what I have for the definition of induced topology

Comment: Well if you are trying to give $S^1$ some topology induced by $f$ then you should define what $f$ is in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the question assuming $f$ is the inclusion map, so that $S^1$ has the subspace topology.  It is a general fact that any subspace $X$ of a Hausdorff space $Y$ with the subspace topology is Hausdorff.  To prove this, just take two distinct points of $X$, take two disjoint open neighborhoods of these points in $Y$, and intersect them with $X$, obtaining two disjoint open sets in $X$.

Comment: @user181662 no problem, you can accept by clicking the checkmark to the left if this answered your question.